Accusative with Adverbial Function
In the Latin sentence Trabes inter se distant binos pedes, the translation is The beams are two feet distant from each other.
In the English sentence, two feet functions adverbially, describing the distance. However, in the Latin, binos pedes is in the accusative case.
Could someone clarify the contexts in which the accusative is used for adverbial functions (e.g., expressing distance), as opposed to the ablative, which is often employed for similar purposes?

In Latin, each case can have a variety of uses, so it's necessary to become familiar with them all. For example, in Allen and Greenough’s New Latin Grammar, there are a number of pages devoted just to uses of the accusative.
With respect to the extent of space, they have the following:

425. Extent of Space is expressed by the accusative.
fossās quīndecim pedēs lātās (B. G. 7.72)
trenches fifteen feet broad
prōgressus mīlia passuum circiter duodecim (id. 5.9)
having advanced about twelve miles
In omnī vītā suā quemque ā rēctā cōnscientiā trānsversum unguem nōn oportet discēdere.   (quoted in Att. 13.20)
In all one's life, one should not depart a nail's breadth from straightforward conscience.

On the same page, they go on to say the following:

b. Distance when considered as extent of space is put in the accusative; when considered as degree of difference, in the ablative (§ 414).
Mīlia passuum tria ab eōrum castrīs castra pōnit.
(B. G. 1.22)
He pitches his camp three miles from their camp.
Quīnque diērum iter abest. (Liv. 30.29)
It is five days' march away.
trīgintā mīlibus passuum īnfrā eum locum (B. G. 6.35)
thirty miles below that place
(below by thirty miles)


This is super helpful. Thank you!
